# Создать папку с помощью Visual studio

Tags: visual-c++

Нужна часть кода, чтобы при запуске приложения он создавал папку в указанном месте
P.s Не очень знаю C++

Answer (score 0):

```
void main()
{
if (CreateDirectory("c:\\new",NULL))
cout << "directory create" << endl;
else
cout << "error create directory" << endl;
}
```